# Exposing API Endpoints for AI Application Deployed on Google AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have deployed an AI model on Google Cloud Platform in the 'SavedModel' format. The model is able to make predictions when I enter sample input data through the 'Test & Use' facility on AI Platform.

Now, I would like to expose API endpoints so that other front end applications (eg. Android) can make use of this deployed model. What is the procedure to do so? I could not find much help in the documentations provided by Google.

Comment: What are your requirements ? Authentication? Rate limit?

Comment: I would like to make REST API calls to my deployed model from a front end application (could be Android, iOS, JavaScript, etc.) to receive predictions in response from the model.

Comment: While you deploy the model in AI platform, you need to be authenticated to pass predictions, we created a guide to use CF which may be helpful. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/ai-machine-learning/empower-your-ai-platform-trained-serverless-endpoints-with-machine-learning-on-google-cloud-functions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on your requirements, but you can make REST API calls with cURL.

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl -X POST -d '{json-input}' https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{project-name}/models/{model-resource-name}:predict\?access_token\=${ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Other resources:

- https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/online-predict#requesting_predictions
- https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/v1/predict-request#http-url-format

Comment: How can you access this in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of path's in order to serve your custom model but to make a concise answer to that question but you can deploy your custom model through an API endpoint following this workaround:

1. Upload your model into a bucket.
2. Create a model resource
3. Create a version.
4. Deploy
5. Once it's deployed, you can call the endpoint in your front-end applications.
   (Bear in mind that batch predictions are not implemented on Python 3.x yet)

Endpoint URL request syntax:

```
POST https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{my-project}/models/{my-model}/versions/{my-version}:predict
```

Not specifying a version would redirect the request to your default version.

Here's some further information about prediction using the [Java library](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/prediction-overview#how_it_works) an overview about [ML Engine predictions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/mlengine/online-prediction/src/main/java/OnlinePredictionSample.java).